# AS2 refering to stage content

Tags: flash, coordinates, actionscript-2, trace, shapes

I have a flash file with 2183 frames, each frame has one drawing. These drawings were not converted to any kind of symbol.

Basically what I need is to trace the _x and _y of each drawing, but I can't seem to find a way to refer to the stage content or frame content or anything that's not a named symbol. Due to the high number of frames, manually converting and naming all of the frames is out of question.

Would you please help me with this issue?

Comment: You cannot access information about arbitrary graphics on the stage - this is why symbols exists. You could potentially use BitmapData to flatten each frame of the stage and find the top-left-most pixel that is not white, but that would not be very performant and I'm not even sure if the AS2 BitmapData API supports all of that.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is not possible at runtime. But you might be able to automate the process of changing graphics to symbols using JSFL:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/extend/WS359E0FA7-1DA9-4c9b-8AE3-CFED6B6B11CECS5.html

JSFL is a scripting language for the Flash IDE (and other adobe products) and allows to automate it. There are libraries that make handling JSFL more powerfull and easier, for example xJSFL:

http://www.xjsfl.com/support/guides/working-with-flash/introduction-to-selectors